# How to open PDF file in Emacs?

Tags: pdf, emacs

I am a new to Emacs. I'm trying to open PDF file but no success.

Also, I tried to open DOCX file and pictures (JPEG, PNG) but failed too. I used M-x image-dired function and doc-view but nothing.

I found [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Document-View.html) but don't know how to get PNG support for Emacs.

If anyone can help?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why would anyone want to view a PDF file in Emacs?

Comment: If you're on Windows, look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650041/emacs-under-windows-and-png-files) for png support.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie For the same reason you want to view it inside a browser?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Just out of curiosity: why would anyone want to leave Emacs only to view a pdf? ;-)

Comment: Because PDF is too rich to leave it to poor viewers such as pdf.js, preview, emacs,... ;-)

Comment: @BrunoLowagie i want to navigate through .pdf like i do in emacs. guess it is possible. that is the reason :)

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen i found already the link you mentioned and followed its steps but nothing.

Comment: @ Kone Ahonen can you tell us more about your emacs version ? How did you install it ?

Comment: And what operating system are you on?

Comment: @KoneAhonen you must confuse me with another author

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen yes indeed. sorry.

Comment: os is windows 7. i have installed emacs v 24.4. as molbdnilo sugessted i visited the link and am now able to open .jpeg files (after including libjpeg-9.dll in emacs/bin directory). however, i still can not open .pdf or .png. i fail to find libpng16.dll and libpng16-16.dll which emacs requested (M-x v RET -> dynamic-library-alist). @homeless

Comment: Viewing a MicrosoftWord document ending in `*.docx` is the subject of a different question (the answer to which *may* be that it is not possible?) and should not be combined with how to vew a `*.pdf` document.  Ghostscript (an external utility) is used to render `*.png` images for `*.pdf` viewing inside Emacs.  And if you are using Windows, then you also need the appropriate `*.dll` files.  Typing `M-x describe-variable RET dynamic-library-alist RET` will give a list of the `*.dll` files needed by Windows to view `*png` files -- then hunt down the files and put them in the Emacs `bin` dir.

Comment: A few targeted Google searches will tell you where to download Ghostscript for Windows -- I use version `9.14`.  Google is also your friend to finding the `*.dll` files.  Some versions of Emacs for Windows come pre-installed with the `*.dll` files - you could either use that installation of Emacs or copy the `*.dll` files out of that distribution over to your current installation.  Keep a running source directory of all your hard work so that you can install Emacs again (e.g., on other machines) as needed.  The variable `doc-view-ghostscript-program` controls the location of `gswin32c.exe`

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide a bit more information as this functionality can vary depending on what platform you are on. It can also depend on what libraries have been compiled into emacs and what other utility programs you have on your system. On Linux and OSX (emacs installed via homebrew), this is fairly easy to get working as the necessary external utilities are easy to install. I don't know about Windows.

The emacs manual has these 2 footnotes in the section on doc-view

> (1) `gs` is a hard requirement.  For DVI files, `dvipdf` or
>   `dvipdfm` is needed.  For OpenDocument and Microsoft Office documents,
>   the `unoconv` tool is needed.
>
> (2) The needed external tools for the document type must be
>   available, and Emacs must be running in a graphical frame and have PNG
>   image support.  If any of these requirements is not fulfilled, Emacs
>   falls back to another major mode.