# PNG Support for Emacs

Tags: emacs, png, zlib, emacs24, libpng

I was trying to add PNG support to my Emacs installation to display png files. Though I found the following and some other links online, I'm still not able to view png files.

[Emacs under Windows and PNG files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650041/emacs-under-windows-and-png-files)

I have copied libpng and zlib1 dll files in my emacs/bin directory and have made sure that they are not outdated but the

```
(image-type-available-p 'png)
```

returns nil. I would like to know if I'm missing something.

I am using Emacs 24.4 on Windows 8.1 64-bit.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There are a few Emacs versions that already have the correct dll files and you can avoid trying to track down all the dll files -- I suggest you find one of those -- there are already several threads that have links to where these builds are located.  You can also download one of those builds and copy the dll files to your current installation.  Google a bit and you'll find several threads.  For example:  http://vgoulet.act.ulaval.ca/en/emacs/windows/

Comment: Thanks for the link. That's a good idea if I'm not able to add the commonly used features myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/

Emacs can also support some other image formats with appropriate libraries. These libraries are all available on the following sites:

1. http://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/files/
     -- leaner, more up-to-date builds, only for 32-bit Emacs
2. http://www.gtk.org/download/win32.php

   http://www.gtk.org/download/win64.php
     -- the GTK project site; offers much fatter builds, but includes
        64-bit DLLs (from the 2nd URL)

Comment: Thanks a lot. The sourceforge project link works perfectly. Will upvote the answer once I have enough rep.